# Dart editor launch configuration

Tags: dart

I am a bit confused about the launch is supposed to work. In my project I have a build.dart and a html file.

What I am doing now is run the build.dart and then run the html.

Building the dart and then refresh the browser window works also.

But I see no option to run the build.dart and then automatic refresh dartium?

Comment: Just to check - is the build.dart you mention the one used to generate web component html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite method is to click on the index.html in the out directory and hit Command-r (or whatever is equivalent on your OS) to run it. This will run build.dart as well as open Dartium.

Comment: Also do it that way, but it sucks a lot if you do web_ui: Due to a bug, you have to start the html inside web/out. It is cumbersome to select the one intermediate html file do get the project started. And finally: Why is there no "default configuration" that is run on ctrl-R ?